# For real emission graphs can we put the additional photons also in the initial state?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

To compute the NLO for e.g. $e^+e^- \rightarrow \mu^+\mu^-(+\gamma)$ in the Schwartz book, we need to compute the real emission graphs for $e^+e^- \rightarrow \mu^+\mu^-\gamma$ to cancel the IR divergences. But why does the additional photon must be in the final state? Could it not be put on-shell also in the initial state i.e. $e^+e^-\gamma \rightarrow \mu^+\mu^-$. It may be that this does not change the cross section, but I don't see it clearly neither do I have an intuitive explanation for it. If we would consider $e^+e^- \gamma\rightarrow \mu^+\mu^-$ the soft photon could come from the field and slightly increase the centre of mass energy.

Comment: Do you mean, can the photon be initial state radiation rather than final state radiation?

Comment: No I mean actually having the $e^+e^-$ system absorbing a (soft) photon in the initial state and going then to $\mu^+\mu^-$